# How can I do InstanceBinding to two different instances of a class without doing `new` in the module?

Tags: java, guice

I have a class `Couple` that takes two `Person`s in its constructor. Each person has a different name. How can I set this up so that Guice will nicely inject everything. (Couple and Person are just arbitrary. I thought it would be nicer than A and B)

```
public class Couple {
    private final Person person1;
    private final Person person2;

    public Couple(@Person1 Person person1, @Person2 Person person2) {
        this.person1 = person1;
        this.person2 = person2;
    }
}

public class Person {
    private final String name;

    public Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

public class CoupleModule {
    private final String name1;
    private final String name2;

    public CoupleModule(String name1, String name2) {
        this.name1 = name1;
        this.name2 = name2;
    }

    protected void configure() {
        install(new PersonModule(name1, name2));
        bind(Couple.class);
    }
}
```

Right now I'm just binding to an instance and calling new for the Persons.

```
public class PersonModule {
    private final String name1;
    private final String name2;

    public PersonModule(String name1, String name2) {
        this.name1 = name1;
        this.name2 = name2;
    }

    protected void configure() {
        bind(Person.class)
             .annotatedWith(Person1.class)
             .toInstance(new Person(name1));

        bind(Person.class)
             .annotatedWith(Person2.class)
             .toInstance(new Person(name2));
    }
}
```

But I prefer to not call new. One option would be to use two provides methods:

```
@Provides @Person1
Person providePerson1() {
    return new Person(name1);
}

@Provides @Person2
Person providePerson2() {
    return new Person(name2);
}
```

However, I'm stilling the one calling new in the module. I prefer to let this be done by Guice. If I only had one person, I would bind the name to an annotated String.

```
protected void configure() {
    bind(String.class)
        .annotatedWith(Name.class)
        .toInstance(name);
    bind(Person.class);
}
```

Now I would like to use the same way, but bind to a different String based on which Person I'm making the binding for. I would like to do something like:

```
protected void configure() {
    bind(Person.class)
        .annotatedWith(Person1.class)
        .withBinding(String.class)
        .annotatedWith(Name.class)
        .toInstance(name1)

    bind(Person.class)
        .annotatedWith(Person2.class)
        .withBinding(String.class)
        .annotatedWith(Name.class)
        .toInstance(name2)
}
```

Is that possible in Guice?

Comment: I believe this is a shallow version of the "Robot Legs" problem, [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4411443/1426891); you currently only inject the Name, though private modules would let you inject that Name arbitrarily deep. (Hopefully it's only true of your _example_ that Name takes no other constructor parameters; if that's the case in your real application, I'd go ahead and use `new`, as injection isn't getting you very much value for its weight/complexity.) May I mark this as a dep of that question?

Comment: jep, that does solve my problem. Interestingly enough, in the solutions proposed, new is being done in the module and not through Guice. Although in my case, name is just a string.

Comment: I'm ok with marking it as a dupe if it's a better artifcat that way.